# Search External Drive with Gnome Documents

Tags: gnome, nautilus, external-hdd

Is there any way for Gnome Documents to access and display documents (HTML/DOCX/ODT) on an External USB Hard Drive? I'm running Ubuntu Gnome 13.04 in a Virtual Machine with the drive connected to it, but Documents doesn't seem to index the drive by default and there's no visible option to make it search the drive. I've checked System Settings too.

Is Gnome Documents purely an online thing, and local stuff is handled with Nautilus? Or is it more useful than meets the eye and I'm just blind?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! 13.04 is not released yet and questions about it are considered off topic as per the [FAQ].

Answer (score 1):

I think Gnome Documents is actually just a simple search UI targeted at showing you the list of documents in various sources. Looking at the source code for `gnome-documents` it seems you probably need to have `tracker` installed, and have it index the contents of removable media, as well as your home directory.

Comment: By default it seems as though tracker disables the indexing of content from removable media. It should be as simple as opening Search and Indexing and selecting the Include removable media box.